# How to pronounce the family name "Penhallow"

Tags: pronunciation, names

How to pronounce the family name *Penhallow*? I'm translating the story "A Tangled Web" by L. M. Montgomery into Russian.

Comment: That's actually a Cornish name.

Comment: @Tristan - ...which likely would have been "Canadianized" when the family moved there. So really its anybody's guess what the pronounciation would have landed on.

Comment: T.E.D., that's a good point. It seems that the question should be asking for a typical Canadian pronunciation of the name.

Comment: Is "Canadianized" a real word or just something used for the purpose of commenting here?

Comment: @Tristan - I know [Americanized](http://www.mifamilyhistory.org/bay/Americanization_Names.htm) is the word used for the same phenomenon with USA immigrants. I made an extrapolation to Canada (and put irony quotes around it, just in case).

Answer (score 7):

I would pronounce that /penˈhæloʊ/ but there might be a particular Cornish way of pronouncing it — Penhallow is a place in Cornwall — or a Canadian way. I can imagine that Cornishmen might say /ˈpeloʊ/ or /ˈpenloʊ/.

Comment: Or possibly even have it rhyme with ‘pallor’!

Answer (score 4):

Being a Penhallow, the name is pronounced as follows, disregarding local accents.

**Pen** (like something you write with)
**ha** ("a" like that in bat, cat etc)
**llow** (like grow, toe etc.)
The emphasis is very subtly on the "ha".

In Russian it is translated as "пенхаллоу" (this is my name in the credits of a Russian TV show I worked on).

Comment: Presumably you mean _Пенхаллоу_: even the Russians capitalise their proper names. (Also, to be exact, it’s a transliteration, not a translation.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that's a common enough name in Canada, but here in the US there would be no canonical way to pronounce "Penhallow", so you'd have to ask the holder of the name.

There is perhaps a certain small subset of names that have an expected "correct" pronunciation, (eg: Smith, Brown, etc), but this is not in them.

Complicating matters is that it contains the word "hallow", which different English accents pronounce differently. I doubt it is consistent across all of Canada. For instance, where I live that word is pronounced with a short *a* and the "ow" as a long *o* for the sense of "to make holy", but more like a short *o* and the "ow" as either a short *a* or more like an "er" if it is in the sense of "a valley between two hills".

Your best bet is probably to either change the question to "Canadians: If you were saddled with this last name, how would you chose to pronounce it?", or to just pick a pronunciation you like, and move on.

Comment: The one between two hills is a *hollow*, not a *hallow*.

Comment: @tchrist  The one between two hills is also a *holler* in some parts of the American South.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to explain this syllable by syllable. I'm a Canadian after all. The sounds are bold.

Penhallow

P**e**n- The E is pronounced like the E in l**e**nd, p**e**nding, r**e**nting, and m**e**nd.

H**a**l- The A is pronounced like the A in m**a**lleable, gr**a**ss, st**a**tistics, and b**a**tter.

L**o**w- The O is pronounced like the O in t**o**e, gr**o**w, s**o**w, m**o**e, thr**o**w, and sc**o**re.

Comment: I pronounce the A in malleable different to that in grass. That's the problem with

Comment: And I think pretty much every native English speaker pronounces the a in ‘statistics’ differently to both the one in ‘malleable’ and the one in ‘grass’ (whether they differ or not).

Comment: @Fatima  Where would you put the stress?  PEN-hallow or pen-HAL-low?

Comment: @mikeY PEN-hallow